# SQOOP import store data in local file system not in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import data from mysql to hdfs via sqoop but after importing its store data in my `/home/<user>/<tablename>` folder not in  hdfs.

```
sqoop import -fs local \
    -jt local \
    -libjars /tmp/sqoop-amar/compile/00992af844025da3f2ee7d83cb03a6b3/user_account.jar \
    --create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/ecom \
    --username root --password 123456 \
    --hive-import --table user_account
```

Comment: Is your `core-site.xml` pointing at `file:///`? And not `hdfs://<namenode>:<port>`?

Answer (score 1):

Please note you are using `-fs local` argument. Due to this argument imported data is stored in local filesystem instead of hdfs.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop command:

```
sqoop import [GENERIC-ARGS] [TOOL-ARGS]
```

One of the options is:

```
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
```

If you use `-fs local` the file will be stored on local file system. You may either specify the name-node & port details of the cluster or just not use `-fs` option, by default it stores in HDFS.

Refer: [Sqoop Docs](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments)

Answer (score 0):

to import to your local directory u need to specify the target directory with the sql table to imprt like --

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip_address:port/db_name? --username XXX --password XXX --driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --table TABLE_NAME --m 1 --target-dir /usr/local/new